# iOS cannot change app name after iOS 11

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Currently, I can upload a newer version of an app to change its app name. However, today, it says in iTunes connect:

> Once submissions are accepted for apps built with the iOS 11 SDK, all new app names will need to be 30 characters or fewer and you’ll only be able to update an app's description when submitting a new version of that app.

Does this mean it's **absolutely impossible to change an app's name** now? How about category, screenshots, available countries, and other options?

Comment: This topic should be closed.  Ask this sort of questions at Apple's Developer forums since it's only people from Apple, Inc. who have the answer.

Comment: The statement from Apple seems quite clear and says nothing about changing an apps name now, nor anything about the other metadata or availability details

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 0):

Found [this discussion](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/255022) on the Apple Developer Forums. Where it basically says the alert only means the description's editability will change from when iOS 11 is released and forward.

Currently, the app description is always editable. However, with the addition of the promotional text the description will become editable only when submitting a new version. App name and other meta data's editability will not change with this update.

> Q: Does this mean all meta data except the app's description will no longer be editable upon submitting a new version of the app, or does it simply mean the description will from here on only be editable upon submitting a new version?
>
> A: *>does it simply mean the description will from here on only be editable upon submitting a new version?*
>
> That, except not from today on.
>
> It's a coming soon change alert when iOS 11 is eventually allowed for store submittals, different from before/now. See the iTunes Connect Developer Guide for which items (currently) are locked/editable at what point in the process.
>
> ['iTC Properties/Platform Version Information'](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW1)